# Wouldn't it be neat to see how much of your reputation comes from asking questions, and how much comes from answering questions?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, reputation-graph

This of course assumes that all reputation points come from asking or answering questions ("what about accepting an answer?" you say -- well I'd say to put that in with the points from asking).

It might be fun to see this extra granularity reflected in the graphing mechanism.  I have a hypothesis that many people may start out earning reputation for asking, but slowly and consistently evolve into earning reputation from answering...  which seems like an excellent progression...  but currently I don't have a good way to test if this is the way things work.

Plus, you could check out users and see if they are primarily an 'asker' or an 'answerer' and what part of the food pyramid they inhabit.  Is that as neat an idea as I think it is?

Comment: What about the points from having a suggested edit approved? ;-) Also, checking the number of questions vs answers in their profile is a pretty good way to see how they fit into the ecosystem. It's [quite obvious](http://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray) where I stand, for example.

Comment: @Cody: that must be some sort of advanced reputation that I am not familiar with yet ;) Even so, knowing how much reputation comes from editing would be highly neat-o also.. so when someone edits you and locks you out of your own question, you can at least appreciate how good they are at it!

Comment: @Cody: Mostly just asking for being able to see it on the graph, so you can watch the evolution at work...  provided you didn't start out highly evolved that is :)

Comment: @Jimmy - He's just kidding. Cody has solved this for himself by just doing answers. Then it is easy to see where the rep comes from.

Comment: @Cody: re: `"It's quite obvious where I stand"` I'll say! Only 60% accept rate! ​‏¤gasp​‏¤  (^_^)

Comment: @Brock: Feel free to provide actual comprehensive answers to those outstanding questions, and I'll be happy to accept them. Or suggest ways to improve the question. :-p (I'm honestly shocked I didn't get such a comment on the last two questions I asked...)

Comment: @Jimmy: No, anyone without full editing privileges (2k+ reputation) has to suggest edits to another person's post. When those edits are approved by other members of the community, you get +2 reputation for suggesting them. It's not a real problem with what you're proposing, just a minor niggle. And my point was just that as a stop-gap way to tell where the rep comes from, you can compare the number of questions a person has asked to the number of answers they've posted. Most of my rep comes from answers, not questions. Others may vary. Neither is bad; both are quite valuable.

Comment: pretty sure this could be answered with a clever http://data.stackexchange.com query...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a good idea using [this query against the *Stack Exchange Data Explorer*](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1699/).

Just keep in mind that the *Data Explorer* server lags about 3 to 4 weeks behind the production server. So the OP, alas, does not show up yet.

---

Note that the SQL *seems* to give believable results for most users, but it's hard to be sure without access to more reputation audits and/or a look-see by a developer.

For example my results were:

```
item                     Reputation                Percent
---------------------    ----------------------    -------
Total (capped)            6858                      100.0
Total (uncapped)          6858                      100.0
Quest Accepted              12                        0.2
Quest Upvotes               50                        0.7
Quest Downvotes             -2                        0.0
Ans Accepted              2820                       41.1
Ans Upvotes               3670                       53.5
Ans Downvotes              -30                       -0.4
Bounties Given           Not in Data Explorer!?       0.0
Bounties Received          300                        4.4
Downvotes Given (est)      -88                       -1.3
Misc Edits                  12                        0.2
Bonus / Other              114                        1.7
Most Recent Date         07/17/2011
```

... Which tracks my reputation audit nicely.  There's a little variance around: tag-edits, bounty-given, and the fact that we can only *estimate* downvote (-1) rep from the sanitized data.

Here's the results for [Cody][2]:

```
item                     Reputation                Percent
---------------------    ----------------------    --------
Total (capped)           33198                       94.2
Total (uncapped)         35240                      100.0
Quest Accepted               6                        0.0
Quest Upvotes              155                        0.4
Quest Downvotes            -10                        0.0
Ans Accepted              8925                       25.3
Ans Upvotes              26100                       74.1
Ans Downvotes              -58                       -0.2
Bounties Given           Not in Data Explorer!?       0.0
Bounties Received           50                        0.1
Downvotes Given (est)     -570                       -1.6
Misc Edits                  10                        0.0
Bonus / Other              632                        1.8
Most Recent Date         07/17/2011
```

The "Bonus/Other" can be explained as follows:

- Everybody gets 1 point that doesn't seem to be included in the `Users.Reputation` value.
- Most of us have 100 points, as an association bonus.
- Some of the `PendingEditRepBonus` seems to be missing.  In my case 46 points, from tag-wiki edits were missing (but I did find 12 points).
- Bounties given are not in the data! So those points, if any, will appear in the "Other" value.
- The Downvote penalty (-1) is only an estimate, since there is no way tell tell -- from the public data -- if a given vote was for a question or an answer.

This SQL assumes that half of the downvotes were for questions.  Any discrepancy will be rolled into the "Other" value.

Comment: Nope, I've never set/awarded a bounty. Not sure what you missed, though. :-)

Comment: @Cody, thanks!  Also seems to call back to `"Or suggest ways to improve the question"`. (hint, bounty, hint) ;)

Comment: @Cody: It seems that you earned 50 points through bounty on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray?tab=bounties

Comment: @Siva: Hmm, yeah. Forgot about that. Bounties aren't much of an incentive for me to answer questions, so I only end up getting them by chance. Like that one, started after I posted my answer. Nice catch.