# Migration PostHistory records are omitted from Data Explorer DB Exports, Why?

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, data-explorer, statistics

Seems from a few posts [as recent as August 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102638/what-are-these-mysterious-values-for-posthistorytype) that Migration records used to be included in the DE DB's PostHistory table. They are currently (Nov 2011) [omitted](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1738/history-type-mystery) and I was just wondering why.

The reason I ask is that some users and I were currently trying to figure out how many [migrated-in Questions go unloved](https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/q/118934/unloved-migrated-questions). But the data to filter for migrated questions only is missing.

**Update**:
As we've been trying to cleanup questions and trying to do a bit of data-mining related to that effort I have noticed that quite a lot of records are omitted from the DE DBs. If nobody can answer *why* this information is missing, does anyone have a list of *what* information is present or missing (the mostly complete schema docs do not mention of what is omitted from the DE DBs).

**Update 2**:
We have not forgotten about this and nobody has given so much as a lousy non-answer response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it was actually not omitted. It is still exported.

..... However, a few months ago <strike>waffles</strike> **Nick Craver** split up the migration post history record so we have 2 different records.

1. Post migrated away
2. Post migrated in

This makes it much easier to write migration based queries.

We export a restricted number of post history records, some must remain private as the information is sensitive. The restriction is "white list" based, so any new post history record types are default omitted.

I fixed this and it will be corrected next time we update data.se and the data dumps.

Comment: It's true, I broke data exports...it was for a good cause though!  Thanks for fixing the exports again Sam!

Comment: Thank you Nick and Sam. I figured there was either a good reason or someone forgot. Thanks again!