# Change "helpful flags" line to include number of declined flags?

Tags: feature-request, flags, profile-page, declined-flags, helpful-flags

I like the new line that lists the number of helpful flags you've had, because now I know when flags get approved by seeing an incrementing number rather than a solid "750" all the time. However, I still don't know when things get declined, because that number is not shown.

Instead of the `helpful flags: ###` line could we generalize it to be `flags: ### helpful, ### declined` so that both numbers are listed? This way, we can notice when flags get declined as well as marked helpful.

[image: flags-on-profile]

Comment: If you click on the helpful flags number, it will give you this information in a summary (in the right margin of the page).

Comment: @Robert: Yes, I know that. But I oftentimes sit there and just refresh my profile page every once in a while to see if the number increases, as a way of telling if a flag has been reviewed.

Comment: that way doesn't look prominent enough; I'd prefer every flag decline to make my browser background bloody red - and keep it that way until I post something at Meta in _declined-flags_ tag

Comment: @gnat: making the whole site `<blink>` would be welcome too

Comment: I got pointed here from this Q: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192858/186983 where i propose a change to show the number of active flags.