# Show number of active flags on profile page

Tags: feature-request, flags, profile-page

Currently, when viewing my profile I see:

> helpful flags:    58

And I think to myself: "Wasn't my recent flags helpful?" since the number hasn't increased.
Clicking the number, however, I see that they are still active.

I propose a change to the profile page that includes the number of active flags as well, for instance:

> flags: 58 helpful / 2 active

Comment: Soft duplicate/quite similar request -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120297/change-helpful-flags-line-to-include-number-of-declined-flags

Comment: If my memory serves me correctly, it used to do that before. I could be completely wrong though.

Comment: Personally I would prefer to add yet another tab, next to "votes", titled "flags" that will show the same data we now see in the flag summary page. But agree that showing number of active flags is good idea, especially for those who cast their first flag and have no way to see it until it is approved. (and if declined they will never see it either)

Comment: @hjpotter92 thanks. I tried searching but that request was just a bit off from what I tried (it doesn't mention the word "active").

Comment: @Matsemann: but it *does* fit in the same pattern. You coud make that a comment on the request.

Comment: @MartijnPieters done