# Can pending flag count be shown on profile?

Tags: feature-request, flags, profile-page

Occasionally I flag something, and then later want to see what happened with the flag. I click once to get to my profile, and can see my flag count:

[image]

Then I click on the "helpful flags" list to see the details. There I can see that my flag is still pending. So far all is fine.

An hour later, if I'm wondering, I probably still remember my count of helpful flags. If I return to my profile and see the number has gone up, I know my flag was handled as helpful. But if it's the same, perhaps the flag I cast is still pending, or perhaps it was declined. I can't tell, I have to click again.

I know that's a fairly narrow column but I think there's room for an indication of how many pending flags you have. Perhaps a (1) or (2) after the word flags? It would save a click for those who were monitoring.

Comment: btw http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192858/show-number-of-active-flags-on-profile-page was a similar request for the old profile page

Answer (score 3):

Until this gets implemented you can use the following userscript to get the same result:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         add pending flags to profile page
// @namespace    http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene
// @version      0.1
// @description  add pending flags
// @author       rene
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/users/*
// @match        *://stackoverflow.com/users/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

// http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/158100

(function() {

    // get the flag summary if we are on our own profile
    if (document.location.pathname.indexOf(StackExchange.options.user.userId.toString()) > 1 ) {
        $.get('/users/flag-summary/' + StackExchange.options.user.userId, function (data) {
            var flags = $(data).find('#flag-stat-info-table a[href*="&status=1"]'),
                totalWaiting = 0;
            // loop over the html anchors to find their number in 
            // in the td of the first column
            flags.each(function() {
                var tds = $(this).parent().parent().find('td.col1').text(),
                    num = parseInt(tds, 10);
                if (num !== NaN) {
                    totalWaiting = totalWaiting + num;
                }
            });
            $('div.impact-card a').each(
                function() {
                    var a = $(this);
                    if (a.text().indexOf('helpful flags') > 0) {
                        a.text(a.text() + ' (' + totalWaiting + ')');
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    }
}());
```

To see its result in action:

[image: helpful flags with (1) pending]

The script is tested in Chrome with Tamper Monkey but should work with Grease Monkey in Firefox as well.