# Automatically inform users who took part in a bad migration

Tags: feature-request, migration, migrated-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Provide direct feedback for rejected migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115716/provide-direct-feedback-for-rejected-migrations)

Closely related to [gnat's recent suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120951/make-it-easier-for-close-voters-at-target-site-to-contact-those-who-voted-for-mi) which I agree with in spirit -

If a migration to a SE site turns out to be a bad one because it gets closed as NaRQ, Off-Topic, or too localized, why not automatically inform the users who caused the migration using a notification bar as you get with new badges and such?

It could read

> Question x that you voted to migrate to X.SE was closed there as "Not a Real Question". Migrating it there may not have been the right choice. If you're unsure, learn more about how to do a good migration here. *(link to a good canonical Meta resource)*

this  would reach *exactly the right people* - those who botched the migration - with zero human effort. There wouldn't be any kind of punishment; just this message. I think this could be incredibly educational.

As to how long after migration a closing would have to happen for this message to be shown, I don't have a perfect answer to that but I'm sure it could be determined. One would want to err on the side of caution - i.e. if in doubt, don't show it. The right recipe would probably be some formula of the number of views vs. time. Alternatively, a fixed per-site time limit (e.g. a day on SO, 3 days on less frequented sites) might work.  There would also be exceptions: If a migrated question gets closed by a mod within a day of migration, the message would be triggered; if it takes, like, 300 views to get closed, it would not.

Comment: Very similar to my feature request, though the time/view limit is new: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115716/provide-direct-feedback-for-rejected-migrations

Comment: @Fabian oh, I didn't know that one, sorry. I think mine is a dupe of yours, I'll add the time limit idea as an answer there.