# "Migrated" question not marked as migrated on source site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration, migration-rejection, migration-notice

[This question was migrated to superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/665921/27-ips-lcd-monitor?noredirect=1) from stackoverflow, and closed by one of our hardworking mods (yay!). Its a clear recommendation question and should have been sealed up in a barrel, encased in concrete, and dumped in the deep ocean. However, it was sent over to superuser. Under normal circumstances, we'd remind the folks on the original site not to migrate such questions. Interestingly on SO, [the question is closed in the regular fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615856/27-ips-lcd-monitor?noredirect=1), rather than migrated.

Unfortunately, this leads to the risk of wanting to [pillory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillory) the wrong people. That said, this smells like a bug to me. So, what just happened?

Comment: No-repro - shows for me.

Comment: This is by design, I think, because the question was closed on Super User the question is returned to Stack Overflow to die there...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is entirely normal behaviour, not a bug. When a migrated question is closed on the target site, the migration is marked as *rejected* and the migration notice on the original question is removed.

You can see this in the [question revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19615856/revisions):

> **Migration Rejected**

Don't worry, the failed migration has been [properly noted in the migration rejection stats](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/rejected) (visible to 10k+ users in the Tools section):

[image: rejected migration]

If you want to berate someone, the same question revision history notes the names of those that marked it for migration to SuperUser.

There is an [open feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115716/provide-direct-feedback-for-rejected-migrations) to automate feedback to users that have a lot of their vote-to-migrate-questions rejected on the target site.