# Why are certain PostHistoryTypeIds not present in the data explorer?

Tags: support, data-explorer

The `PostHistoryTypes` according to the Data Explorer are given [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/125094). However, certain `HistoryTypeIds` are never present while querying the Data Explorer. The most notable missing id for my personal data task is 17 - `Post Migrated`. I don't see them present either on [Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/125093) or [Super User](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/edit/125095). Is there any particular reason for this?

Comment: Probably because Data.SE doesn't track across multiple sites, for that specific ID.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I am sorry - does this mean that the `PostHistoryTypeId` = 17 is of no value? I want to get all questions on `Stack Overflow` which are migrated to other platforms. What is the best way to get this data?

Answer (score 2):

This is now [possible by using  PostHistoryType 'Migrated away'](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201406/posts-migrated-away) as described in the [Database schema post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede).

```
select ph.PostId as [Post Link]
     , ph.CreationDate
     , ph.UserId as [User Link]
     , ph.UserDisplayName
     , ph.Comment as target
from posthistory ph
inner join posts p on p.id = ph.postid
where posthistorytypeid = 35 -- Migrated away
and p.posttypeid = 1 -- question
order by CreationDate
```

At time of posting this query returns 691 rows.

I'm not sure if the 'whitelist' mentioned in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120102/158100) only applies to a certain posthistorytypeid or also on specific posts within a certain type.