# Is there a way to filter out merged questions from the data explorer?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I'm writing a query to find old questions without much answer attention, to help combat [the xkcd "Wisdom of the Ancients"](http://xkcd.com/979/) problem. I can filter out closed posts with `p.ClosedDate IS NULL`, but I'm getting *merged* questions in the results — a lot of 'em. How can I filter these out too?

Comment: Can you point to some results of [your query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2292/find-questions-ripe-for-the-revival-and-necromancer-badges) that are merged questions?  (I spot-checked a couple dozen and didn't see any.)  If you can, we might be able to determine an indirect way to detect merged posts.

Comment: @BrockAdams — run it on Photo-SE, and look at the top 3.

Comment: Well, that was a bust.  There's nothing in the question record or comments that hints that the Q's are merged. ... Looks like the only recourse is to **feature-request that `PostHistoryTypes​` value `18` (Question Merged) data be put back in SEDE**.

Comment: Thanks @Brock. Should I do that _here_, or a new question?

Comment: I'd vote for a new question.  Maybe reference this Q and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102638/what-are-these-mysterious-values-for-posthistorytype .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround — Merged posts are apparently also Locked in the post history, so PostHistoryType 14 works as well as 18. That means this query:

https://data.stackexchange.com/photography/query/56730/find-questions-ripe-for-the-revival-and-necromancer-badges

now does what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

I executed the following query, and got the following output:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM PostHistoryTypes​
```

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

You can search for a question for which one of the history entries (the table is "PostHistory") contains 18 as value of `PostHistoryTypeId`.

I tried executing the following query on a site with much less questions than Stack Overflow (Drupal Answers):

```
SELECT
    p.Id AS [Post Link], t.name as [Edit type]
FROM
    Posts p
INNER JOIN 
    PostHistory h ON h.PostId = p.Id
INNER JOIN 
    PostHistoryTypes t ON t.Id = h.PostHistoryTypeId 
WHERE 
    p.ParentID IS NULL AND t.Id > 10​
```

The only case where I found a "Post Deleted" entry is when the question has been successively undeleted; this would confirm what Jeff Mercado is saying: Entries about deletion, and merging don't appear in SEDE.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: 18, not 17. Thanks — this looks promising. _Except_: http://data.stackexchange.com/photography/q/122085/looking-for-merged-questions — there don't appear to be any history entries of that type in the data explorer database. Stripped out? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Whoops… I don't know why, but I read _migrated_ instead of _merged_.

Comment: Well, it's still on the right track, except for how it doesn't work. :)

Comment: @mattdm: Unfortunately like deletions, it appears merges will not appear in the SEDE.

Comment: The merged posts are still there, though; you just can't tell if that's why they have no answers. Shame.

Answer (score 1):

See [this "History-type mystery" query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1738/history-type-mystery) and [What are these mysterious values for PostHistoryType?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102638/what-are-these-mysterious-values-for-posthistorytype)

What that shows is that SEDE ***did*** once record at least 3661 merged questions, but **now that information has been expunged!**

From [Kevin Montrose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose):

> Most of these weren't meant to be included... They probably won't be
> included in the next dump.

So, there's no way to (easily) detect merged questions unless you can get that info feature-requested back into SEDE.

Answer (score 0):

Based on mattdm workaround (looking for Locked posts instead of Merged posts), and kiamlaluno base query formatting, I came up with:

```
SELECT
    p.Id AS [Post Link], p.CreationDate
FROM
    Posts p
INNER JOIN
    PostHistory h ON h.PostId = p.Id
WHERE
    h.PostHistoryTypeId = 14
AND
    p.ParentId is null
AND
    p.AnswerCount = 0
Group By
    p.Id, p.CreationDate
ORDER BY
    p.CreationDate
```

Currently, [my query returns 1850 likely merged questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/960426/merged-questions).

Unfortunately, it also contains Migrated questions.