# Please restore visibility of "Question Merged" PostHistoryType in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, merged-questions

I'm trying to make a query to search out older, unloved questions (targets for the Necromancer and Revival badges as a framing device) in order to help combat the [xkcd "Wisdom of the Ancients" problem.](http://xkcd.com/979/)

There's several attempts at making such queries, but the problem is that they seem to include questions which have been merged away. On Photo-SE, it's enough of the results as to make the query less useful. I asked for [help on how to fix that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116410/is-there-a-way-to-filter-out-merged-questions-from-the-data-explorer), and it looks like we need the data explorer to have a value that's stripped out *not* stripped out. Specifically, this is a feature request to **please include PostHistoryTypes​ value 18 (Question Merged) in SEDE**.

Thanks! (Or, if you have another clever way to accomplish this without, please see [my original question on the topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116410/is-there-a-way-to-filter-out-merged-questions-from-the-data-explorer).)

Comment: Matt already discussing with Geoff, see no reason we can not add it back in

Comment: @waffles *poke* *pokepokepoke* -- Any word on this? Did it come back and go away again? (There don't seem to be any PostHistory objects with PostHistoryTypeId 18 in the explorer...)

Answer (score 3):

Shameless bump, since it was apparently "approved" two months ago but [still isn't in the DE dumps](https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/61709).

Sorry, don't hate me!

Comment: at least you're not using a poking stick... :)